# Change argument before passing to hook in rails generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, thor

I'm trying to make simple view generator and using DRY principle, I don't want to have my own html (erb/haml/slim) templates. I'd like my generator to hook to existing template engine and pass it some arguments.

My `view_generator.rb` file looks like this:

```
class ViewGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
  source_root File.expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)
  argument :attributes, :type => :array, :default => [], :banner => "field:type field:type"

def some_custom_method
  (...)
end

hook_for :template_engine, :as => :scaffold

end
```

Everything works fine like this. What I'd like to do in my `some_custom_method` is to add couple of attributes:

```
def some_custom_method
  new_attribute = Rails::Generators::GeneratedAttribute.new("description")
  new_attribute.type = :integer
  attributes << new_attribute
end
```

What happens is that I insert `new_attribute` in `attributes` array, but when the `hook_for` is executed, the `attribute` variable reverts back to original one passed from command line.

How can I bypass this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the point `some_custom_method` is called, attributes are already set (via `ARGV`) and by checking the code I don't see a clear way to alter them from there. You can use another approach by overriding `start` class method in your generator and manipulate the args directly, like this:

```
class ViewGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
  # your code ...
  def self.start(args, config)
    args.insert(1, 'description:integer') # 0 being the view name
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I inserted that method, but it still doesn't work.
I tried making it both public and private. Also, I'm not sure it ever gets called because I inserted some debugging "puts" calls and nothing got printed to console.

Comment: My bad, I used the wrong the name for the function, please check the answer again.